# Compilation error due to ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in main

Tags: java

Hello All i hope all is Well. Im finalizing a program im writing for an assignment and I encounted a `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0` error. I attempted to trouble shoot it based on previous Tutorital Work with no luck. I've done similar, smaller projects in the past using the same base code with no Problems.

```
public class ArithmeticWithFractions {

    private static String Num1;
    private static String Num2;
    private static String Denom1;
    private static String Denom2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Num1 = args[0];
        Denom1 = args[1];
        Num2 = args[2];
        Denom2 = args[3];

        int NumeratorOne = Integer.parseInt(Num1);
        int NumeratorTwo = Integer.parseInt(Num2);

        int DenominatorOne = Integer.parseInt(Denom1);
        int DenominatorTwo = Integer.parseInt(Denom2);

        Fraction FirstFraction = new Fraction(NumeratorOne, DenominatorOne);
        Fraction SecondFraction = new Fraction(NumeratorTwo, DenominatorTwo);

        displayresults(FirstFraction, SecondFraction);

    }

    public static void displayresults(Fraction fr1, Fraction fr2) {

        System.out.println("java ArithmeticWithFractions");
        System.out.println("--- Basic operations with fractions ---");

        Fraction fr3 = fr1.Add(fr2);
        System.out.println("The sum: " + fr1 + "+" + fr2 + "=" + fr3);

        fr3 = fr1.Subtract(fr2);
        System.out.println("The difference: " + fr1 + "+" + fr2 + "=" + fr3);

        fr3 = fr1.Product(fr2);
        System.out.println("The product: " + fr1 + "+" + fr2 + "=" + fr3);

        fr3 = fr1.Quotient(fr2);
        System.out.println("The quotient: " + fr1 + "+" + fr2 + "=" + fr3);

    }
}

class Fraction {

    private int numerator;
    private int denominator;

    public Fraction() {

        numerator = 0;
        denominator = 1;

    }

    public Fraction(int numerator, int denominator) {

        this.numerator = numerator;
        this.denominator = denominator;

    }

    public Fraction Add(Fraction other) {

        int newNumerator = ((other.numerator * denominator)
                + (numerator * other.denominator));
        int newDenominator = denominator * other.denominator;
        Fraction NewFraction = new Fraction(newNumerator, newDenominator);
        return NewFraction;

    }

    public Fraction Subtract(Fraction other) {

        int newNumerator = ((other.numerator * denominator)
                - (numerator * other.denominator));
        int newDenominator = denominator * other.denominator;
        Fraction NewFraction = new Fraction(newNumerator, newDenominator);
        return NewFraction;

    }

    public Fraction Product(Fraction other) {

        int newNumerator = numerator * other.numerator;
        int newDenoinator = denominator * other.denominator;
        Fraction NewFraction = new Fraction(newNumerator, newDenoinator);
        return NewFraction;

    }

    public Fraction Quotient(Fraction other) {

        int newNumerator = numerator * other.denominator;
        int newDenominator = denominator * other.numerator;
        Fraction NewFraction = new Fraction(newNumerator, newDenominator);
        return NewFraction;

    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.numerator + "/" + this.denominator;
    }

    public int calcCommonDenominator(int numerator, int denominator) {
        if (numerator % denominator == 0) {
            return denominator;
        }
        return calcCommonDenominator(denominator, numerator % denominator);
    }

    void reduce() {
        int gcd = calcCommonDenominator(numerator, denominator);
        numerator /= gcd;
        denominator /= gcd;

    }
}
```

The error happens at Line 5 `String Fraction = args[0];`, if complied successfully the program should allow 4 Integers to be entered within one single Command Line argument, the first two being the first Numerator and First denominator and the last two bein the second numerator and denominator.

Comment: A. Are you sure this is a compile time error and not a run time error?  B. Did you provide arguments when running so that args has values?

Comment: How you are running the main method? Are you passing arguments to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your premise correctly, you want to allow two fractions to be entered as command line arguments.  For example, `1/2` and `3/4` would be entered as:

```
1 2 3 4
```

If so, then you may simply capture these components:

```
String Num1 = args[0];
String Denom1 = args[1];
String Num2 = args[2];
String Denom2 = args[3];
```

Line 5 of your current code makes no sense:

```
String Fraction = args[0];
```

A `Fraction` object has no direct relationship to a `String`.  We need to create an instance of `Fraction` using the constructor provided, but that requires two integers.

**Edit:**

Here is what one implementation might look like:

```
public class ArithmeticWithFractions {
    private String num1;
    private String num2;
    private String denom1;
    private String denom2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        num1 = args[0];
        denom1 = args[1];
        num2 = args[2];
        denom2 = args[3];
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This would definitely support a larger range of fractions and be a more useful solution than the true answer to the current question asked

Comment: Thankyou! A follow up question, How would i make String Num1, Num2 etc Global? IE declare outside of main.

Comment: Java doesn't really have the notion of global variables the same way that other languages such as e.g. C++ has.  But, you may declare the fields as `static final` at the `ArithmeticWithFractions` class level.

Comment: Im currently trying to share variables within the same class so i made String num1 etc Global but as it requires args[] it does not work (see image below, im trying to parse fr1 and fr2 to displayresults) https://i.imgur.com/a2x3ISY.png

Comment: @MichaelCheng Check the updated answer.  Just declare the numerators and denominators as class level fields.  I don't know if you even really need this, but the above is one way to do it.

Comment: Thankyou!! Please check above as i edited the code provided. I still get the error  java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 at line 10 with Num1 = args[0];. im entering the input in command line as 1234 no spaces one line.

Comment: i have a question. Is it possible to use substring as input for what im trying to do?

Comment: You should open a new question, I think.

Answer (score 0):

`java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0` Will occur(In your case) when you try to run the program without giving the input arguments (command line arguments).

So try to run the program with command line arguments. like below

```
      java ArithmeticWithFractions 1234
```

Advises:
Change the name of the variable "Fraction" at String Fraction = args[0]; to something meaningful say input.

```
String input = args[0];
```

<strike>String Num1 = input.substring(0); String Num2 = input.substring(1);String Denom1 = input.substring(2);String Denom2 = input.substring(3);</strike>

And your command line argument should be like 1234 (no spaces).

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Thanks edit the answer, it was my mistake.

Comment: Nothing wrong with spaces, assuming you want multiple input arguments.